# Split 2 large columns into two

Tags: r, r-markdown

I created a long frequency table with 1234 obj and I'd like to print it using Rmarkdown. Here you have an example:

```
  Mod | Freq
  aa | 23
  ab | 34
  ac | 55
  ad | 11
  ae | 1
  af | 22
```

What I would like to have is this:

```
  Mod| Freq |      Mod | Freq
  aa | 23 ad |      ad | 11
  ab | 34 ae |      ae | 1
  ac | 55 af |      af | 22
```

I tried to look for the same question, but most of the answers were about separating data in two. Ex: aa --> a | a

Here you have a reproducible example:

```
  a = data.frame(Mod=c("aa","ab","ac","ad","af","ag"), Freq=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Comment: Perhaps `cbind(a[1:3,], a[4:6,])`

Comment: Seems's to be a rmarkdown question. Maybe you take a look at `knitr::kable()` or `pander::pandoc.table()`. You can create tables by calling this functions within R code chunks.

Comment: @nevrome I'm using kable to print the tables. However, I think it is easier to split the columns into two and then use kable to print it than looking for different options within pandoc.table() :) .

Comment: @akrun Ok, I got it!.
`cbind(table2[1:(nrow(table2)/2),], table2[((nrow(table2)/2)+1):nrow(table2),])
nrow(table2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
t1 = a[1:(nrow(a)/2),]
t2 = a[(nrow(a)/2+1):nrow(a),]
knitr::kable(list(t1,t2))
```